# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) - AngularJS - Jersey API

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey

I have a AngularJS web app calling my own Java Jersey API. Everything run on localhost at now.

This is the Angular call:

```
function Create(user) {
        return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/NobelGrid/api/users/create/', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
}
```

This is my code snippet of REST:

```
@Path("/create")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
public Response create(String data) {

    UserDataConnector connector;
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(data);

    User userToCreate = new User(response.getString("surname"), response.getString("name"),
            response.getString("mail"), response.getString("username"), response.getString("password"), 0);

    try {

        connector = new UserDataConnector();
        connector.createUser(userToCreate);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK) // 200
            .entity(userToCreate)
            .build();

}
```

I simply insert an user on my own MySql DB.

**The procedure goes well** cause the user is added in the Db, anyway it returns me that error.

[image]

[image]

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: 500 indicates something wrong at server end during request processing. So add your server error log.

Comment: @mmuzahid I know this. But as I said, on server side seems everything goes well: the user is added to the BD. I execute all the service, instruction by instruction in debug mode and no exceptions was occurred.

Comment: why that extra `/` is comming after `/create` in url ? I think it should be : `http://localhost:8080/NobelGrid/api/users/create`

Comment: I don't know this @ojuskulkarni but I repeat: the code runs well on server side. It's a little bit strange

Comment: Anyway @ojuskulkarni also removing the '/' I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
function Create(user) {
    return $http({
             'url':'/NobelGrid/api/users/create',
             'method': POST,
             'data': user
           }).then(function () {
             // .....
           });
}
```

Comment: OK. The keyword is `method` not `type`. And I have the same error of the original question in the post. :/

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post('http://localhost:8080/NobelGrid/api/users/create/', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));`

```
var config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
};

$http.post('http://localhost:8080/NobelGrid/api/users/create/', $httpParamSerializer(user), config).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
```

You'll need to inject $httpParamSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the annotation @Produces instead of @Consumes so you won't be able to pass a JSON if it's supposed that you shouldn't.